# Batch/VBS script to save Excel file as is

Tags: excel, csv

Is there a way to automate opening every file in a given directory and doing the following:

1. Open the CSV file
2. Save the CSV file (prompts"the file may contain features that are not compatible with CSV. Do you want to keep the workbook in this format?)
3. Select Yes
4. Close the file (prompts "Do you want to save the changes you made to fileName.csv?")
5. Select Yes

The CSV file comes in from a remote server and is incompatible at first.  When I manually open and save then close the file it gets a tiny bit smaller in size then is compatible to use.  I'm assuming there is some difference such as removing commas or semi colons.

Would using a VBS script be the best way to handle a problem like this?  And how would I write a script for the save as part?

Comment: A CSV is just a text file. If you can work out what the change is to make it , 'compatible' you can probably make the change without using Excel. Excel can have many other unwanted side effects which may cause you problems in future. In fact it's the first time I've ever heard of Excel fixing a CSV instead of breaking it

Comment: It;s more so a company we work with need it in excel format.  They weren't willing to convert it themselves so I'm doing it for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to automate this with the [`Workbook.Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

Dim path
path = "C:\path\to\folder"

Dim fso, fle
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder(path).Files
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fle.Path)
    xlBook.Save
    xlBook.Close
Next
```

---

References:

- [Scripting.FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.84).aspx) object, [Scripting.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx) object
- [Excel.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) object, [Excel.Application.Workbooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820765.aspx) property
- [Excel.Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) method
- [Excel.Workbook.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585.aspx) method

Comment: Awesome I'll try this out and upvote your answer if it works! Would this be in a VBS script?

Comment: @CodingMageSheen Yes, although the objects, methods and properties used would be exactly the same under any Automation-supporting environment -- any .NET language, Python, Javascript under Windows Script Host, Delphi, or VBA/VB6.

Comment: It seems that when I save it as a VBS file text document and run it.  It asks me which program I want to open it with.  I have it scheduled to run with windows Task Scheduler

Comment: The command line you need is something like this: `CScript <path to your file>`. See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb490816.aspx

Comment: @CodingMageSheen Re-pinging for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659422/batch-vbs-script-to-save-excel-file-as-is/42659491?noredirect=1#comment72447057_42659491) comment.

Comment: I am receiving an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Open' " when I try to run the script

Comment: @CodingMageSheen Fixed. [`Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) is a method of the [`Workbooks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841074.aspx) collection, not the [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) object.

Comment: Oh I see thank you

Comment: @CodingMageSheen No. `Open` takes `fle.Path`, which is the path of the file to open. It returns a `Workbook` object which represents the newly opened workbook; at which point that object can be accessed via the `xlBook` variable.

Comment: OMG it worked the last thing though is that it prompts me "Do you want to save the changes you've made" in the script can I make it automatic to say yes? Also thank you so much Zev you're a life saver!

Comment: I'll try changing to:  ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

Comment: @CodingMageSheen (1) You mean `xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True`; I don't think `ThisWorkbook` is available from an external program. (2) Also, you can just pass `True` into the `Close` method -- `xlBook.Close True` -- although explicitly naming the parameter is perhaps more readable. (3) What happened with the compilation error?

Comment: The compilation error was my fault I copied and pasted your changed code but left one line in from old code.  I'll try passing in true after xlBook.Close by running SaveChanges:=True it didn't prompt me anymore but it also didn't save it properly.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you Zev for taking the time to help me :)